Request for a method to map test functions to the functions they test
I am looking for a way to efficiently map test functions to the specific functions or modules they test. This would help in understanding the coverage and relationships between the test suite and the codebase. Specifically, I'd like to:

Identify which test functions are associated with which functions or modules in the pandas library.

Determine if there's a built-in tool, strategy, or script to extract this mapping.Thank you


I have been trying to use git blame and commit history analysis to trace which test functions were added or modified alongside new or updated functions in the codebase. The goal is to map these test functions to the specific functions or modules they test.

I think you are looking for a tool for requirements traceability. One I have worked with before is named Reqtify, but certainly this is not the only option.
Basically, you define requirement IDs and tag your requirements, the functions in your implementation and the test functions in your test code with these IDs (e.g. as a comment in the code). The tool can then browse through all the sources and evaluate the test coverage and show you the tracing in a conventient way, i.e. you can hop from a requirement to the place(s) in the implementation to the place(s) in the test code and backwards from the test code to the implementation to the requirement(s).
